# Apple Game Center "Delete test data"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, app-store-connect, game-center

I am making an iOS application that uses Apple Game Center. I used a sandbox account for testing my leaderboards.

I want to delete my test data from the leaderboards using the "Delete Test Data" button in itunes connect.
[image]

After pressing the button it says "Delete Test Data: Requested"
[image]

After this i wait for a while (like 15 minutes). Then the button becomes active again if i reload the page. However when i restart my applicaion the leaderboards still shows my data.

Do i need to wait longer or is there something else i can do to delete the test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my solution:

I waited a few hours. Then I had to delete my application from the Game Center application. After that i reinstalled my app. But there was still a score in one of the leaderboards (Most data got deleted). 
Then i deleted the leaderboard (the one with data) on iTunes Connect and remade it. Then delete the app from Game Center and reinstalled again.

After this my data was gone.

Answer (score 4):

Try to read help popup which Apple provides for you:

[image]

You are just sending a request to delete data, actual deletion is not performed.